# C# Linq XML, check for specific value and parse to array

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<NewDataSet>
   <Data>
     <ElementDefinition>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <QUANTITY>0</QUANTITY>
     </ElementDefinition>
     <ElementDefinition>
      <ID>2</ID>
      <QUANTITY>1</QUANTITY>
     </ElementDefinition>
   </Data>
</NewDataSet>
```

I need to create an array which contains all ElementDefinitions which contain a QUANTITY element with a value other then 0.

I tried:

```
var f = XDocument.Load(path);
var xe = f.Root.Elements("QUANTITY").Where(x => x.Value != "0").ToArray();
```

But that doesn't seem to work. With the above XML the array should contain 1 item, but it stays 0.

After that I need to create a string for each ElementDefinition in the array, the string must contain the value of the corresponding ID element.

For that I tried:

```
foreach (string x in xe)
{
   string ID = //not sure what to do here
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
var ids = f.Root.Descendants("ElementDefinition")
           .Where(x => x.Element("QUANTITY").Value != "0")
           .Select(x => x.Element("ID").Value);
```

As you want the ID, it is not very helpful to select all QUANTITY nodes. Instead, select exactly what you specified in your question:

All ElementDefinitions (`Descendants("ElementDefinition")`), that have a QUANTITY with a Value other than 0 (`Where(x => x.Element("QUANTITY").Value != "0"`). From the resulting nodes, select the ID (`Select(x => x.Element("ID").Value)`).

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! It seems to function now. One 'noob' question..: How to write every ID to a string (will be a XML WriteString function)? Do I need to use foreach?

Comment: You already have all the IDs as strings in the `ids` variable. What else do you need?

Comment: I need each individual ID into a seperate string. But if I understand you correctly its a string array now. So I can use `foreach(id in ids)`?

Answer (score 0):

Yo can replace with

```
var xe = f.Root.Elements("Data/ElementDefinition/QUANTITY").Where(x => x.Value != "0").ToArray();
```